# how to get rid of HTML 5 validation message with our own custom validation message

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate `required` fields of form in HTML 5 with custom messages that are shown like a tooltip text near the field.
Here is the HTML code that I am trying for this purpose:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="validation">
  Name:<input type="text" id="nome"  name="nome" required="required" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Name is required field')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" /><br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Above code is working fine in google chrome except in mozilla in following case:

- press submit button, it will give validation message "Name is
  required field"
- fill something and then before pressing submit type backspace key on 
  keyboard to erase name completely. When it is completely erased it shows message
  "Please fill out this field" on its own.Whereas it should again display a message "Name is
  required field" or display just nothing.

Can some one test and provide an alternative solution for doing this in Mozilla.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in latest firefox - version 41.0.2

Comment: @db579 can you please tell me your firefox version

Comment: @db579 no its there in version 41 also

Comment: How are you testing? I'm not able to reproduce it

Comment: first, press the submit button it will give "Name is required field" message. second, fill some name in it, then before pressing submit erase the name completely. In my case on erasing the name completely, its showing a message "Please fill out this field".

Comment: Yes I'm doing exactly the same and I don't get that in firefox 41. That's why I'm asking, there must be something different about your setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "novalidate" attribute to the form element to disable html5 build-in validation, and then handle all the validation by javascript yourself.

Comment: can you provide me the code for this. I am unable to this. Not that good in javascript.

Comment: @JSK don't write validation on your own, you probably need a library. if you are using jquery, you may want to try this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the one field, then you could always just check for that event on the oninput:

```
oninput="if(this.value==''){this.setCustomValidity('Name is required field')} else {this.setCustomValidity('')};"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j1c935ex/2/

For tidier code, you'd be better calling a function, especially if you are doing this on several fields.